# Call variables from the pivot function

Tags: sql-server, function, pivot, call

Does someone know how I can call a variable from my function pivot?

```
USE Runtime;                                   --Call database
DECLARE @Currentday varchar(20)                --Declare variables
DECLARE @StartDay varchar(20)                  --""
DECLARE @EndDay varchar(20)                    --""
----------------------------
SET @Currentday = GETDATE()
SET @StartDay = dateadd(DAY, -5 ,@Currentday)  --Current day left 5 days to get start day
SET @EndDay = dateadd(DAY, -1,@Currentday)     --Current day left 1 day to get end day
----------------------------
SELECT [TagName], [@StartDay], [@EndDay]       --How get data from this variable to put at Columns
FROM [Runtime].[dbo].[Reporte_Test1]           --Table name
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Valor)
    FOR [Dia] in ([@StartDay], [@Endday])      --How call data from this variable, Data of the dates named in the columns
) AS P;
-----------------------------
```

Comment: FYI there is a code formatting tool in the question editor.

Comment: Remove the `[]`'s from the variables in the query.